# How to get data from a form and redirect the user to another page?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a form that you can see below. When the submit button is pressed, i want a script called "Orders.php" to send all the data to a database. Also, when the button is pressed, i want the user to be redirected to another page. The problem is that now when the php file is in the `action` property, the user sees the php code..

Any ideas on how to fix this?

***HTML***

```
<form id="TheForm" action="orders.php" method="post">
            <div id="Row">
                <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="*Förnamn" required >
                <input type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="*Efternamn" required >
            </div>      
            <div id="Row">
                <input type="email" id="FirstEmail" placeholder="*e-postadress" autocomplete="on" required >
                <input type="email" id="SecondEmail" placeholder="*Verifiera e-postadress" autocomplete="off" required >
            </div>
            <div id="Row">
                <input type="text" id="Town" placeholder="*Ort" required >
            </div>  
            <div id="Row"> 
                <input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="*Adress" required >
            </div>
            <div id="Row">
                <input type="text" id="PostCode" placeholder="*Postnummer" required >
            </div>
            <div id="Row">
                <input type="text" id="MobileNumber"  placeholder="*Mobilnummer" required >
                <input type="text" id="TelephoneNumber" placeholder="Telefonnummer" >
            </div>
            <textarea id="Comment" placeholder="Förslag på hur vi skulle kunna förbättra oss!"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="SlutSidan.html" value="Skicka">
        </form>
```

***Orders.php***

```
    <?php
$connect = mysql_connect(“server_name”, “admin_name”, “password”); 
if (!connect) 
{ 
    die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_select_db(“database_name”, $connect);
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: how can the user see the php code? do you have your server well configured that it runs the php file correctly?

Comment: Not really the experienced in webdev.. not sure what the server well is. They see the code  as if the php was an html file

Comment: There's no such thing as a "server well". "well" is an adverb modifying "configured".

Comment: lol sry... im not as concerned about the php code as much as i am about sending all the data to the .php and redirecting at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can find your form data in the `$_POST` variable like `$_POST['name']`

and to forward it to another page you can use the following function

```
header( "Location: url/to/mySecondPage.php" );
```

Comment: the first: in the php code? Second: in the html file or the form tag?

Comment: isnt there a way of just sending the data to the php at the same time redirecting them to another page? or does it have to be done in php?

Comment: it has to be done in php, perhaps you missed to open the php tag check your code for the `<?php`, this is the only thing I can think for having your php code shown as its thought an html code

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

### change your form

Now it will take your user where you want him to go

```
<form id="TheForm" action="users/final/destination.php" method="post">
  <!-- add this hidden input -->
  <input type="hidden" name="actionScript" value="orders" />
  ...
</form>
```

### change `users/final/destination.php`

This should be on the top of the file

```
<?php
// Check if this file has been requested through your form
if (isset($_POST['actionScript'])) {
  // you may want to encapsulate this in a function
  ob_start();
  require 'orders.php';
  $debug_info = ob_get_clean();
}
// done, now do everything you wanted in usersFinalDestination.php
```

- no header redirect required
- you may want to log your debug info for errors
- you can encapsulate your `orders.php` script in a function to avoid variable collisions

Answer (score 0):

```
Okay, first here is your HTML file:

<!-- HTML FILE -->

YOU MUST HAVE "name" attribute in "input" tag to use its value in php file.

<form id="TheForm" action="orders.php" method="post">
   <div id="Row">
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">
                <input type="text" id="Surname" name="Surname" >
    </div>  

</form>

Now here is your PHP file (just be sure to put "<?php" at starting and "?>" at end of php file ):
orders.php

<?php 


$connect = mysql_connect(“server_name”, “admin_name”, “password”); 
if (!connect) 
{ 
    die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_select_db(“database_name”, $connect);

$_POST["Name"];//to access input field value with name="Name"
$_POST["Surname"];// to access input field value with name="Surname"

//Once you are done with saving data to database you can redirect to another page using:

header("Location:  redirect.php");


?>
```